How to compute moving average convergence divergence without using pandas ewm function?
I'm trying to compute the moving average divergence convergence (MACD) which is a technical indicator in trading.  To compute MACD we have to find out exponential moving average over a certain period or a time window n(I will be providing the procedure, code on how the moving average  and a sample input before the signal column is computed). The signal values range from -10 to 10.  I kept getting KeyError: 'close'. I could not understand how to proceed further please do let me know how I can correct this. 
     # How to compute ema ?
    
    # 1. Calculate the SMA
    
    # (Period Values / Number of Periods)
    # 2. Calculate the Multiplier
    
    # (2 / (Number of Periods + 1) therefore (2 / (5+1) = 33.333%
    # 3. Calculate the EMA
    # For the first EMA, we use the SMA(previous day) instead of EMA(previous day).
    
    # EMA = {Close - EMA(previous day)} x multiplier + EMA(previous day)
    
    
    # How to compute macd ?
    
    # Calculate the short-term EMA (Exponential Moving Average): This is often based on a 12-period EMA.
    # Calculate the long-term EMA: This is often based on a 26-period EMA.
    # Calculate the MACD Line: Subtract the long-term EMA from the short-term EMA.
    # Calculate the Signal Line: Calculate a 9-period EMA of the MACD Line to create the Signal Line.
    
    
    def compute_ema(df,n):
        df['sma'] = df['close'].rolling(n).mean()
        multiplier = 2/(n + 1)
        df.dropna(inplace=True)
        df['ema'] = np.nan
        for i in range(len(df)):
            if i == 1:
                df.loc[df.index[i], 'ema'] =  (df.loc[df.index[i],'close'] - df.loc[df.index[i - 1],'sma']) * multiplier + df.loc[df.index[i - 1], 'sma']
                # df['ema'].iloc[i] = (df['close'].iloc[i] - df['sma'].iloc[i-1]) + df['sma'].iloc[i-1]
            else:
                df.loc[df.index[i], 'ema'] =  (df.loc[df.index[i],'close'] - df.loc[df.index[i - 1],'ema']) * multiplier + df.loc[df.index[i - 1], 'ema']
        return df
df['fast'] = compute_ema(df, n=12)
df['slow'] = compute_ema(df, n=26)
df['macd'] = df['fast'] - df['slow']
df['signal'] = compute_ema(df['macd'],n)
KeyError: 'close'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[41], line 1
----> 1 df['signal'] = compute_ema(df['macd'],n)

Cell In[21], line 24
     23 def compute_ema(df,n):
...
   3815     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3816     #  the TypeError.
   3817     self._check_indexing_error(key)
        


df['macd'] in compute_ema(df['macd',n) doesn't have a column/index close as needed in the first line of the function. I think you may need just compute_ema(df,n).

@Quang Hoang the problem with that is dataframe would compute the signal column using the close values. we need the dataframe to use macd column while computing the signal. I have tried that way it gave very high values which isn't  correct

You're contradiction yourself. If you want macd column, then replace 'close' with 'macd' inside the function. Why do you have close all over that function?

I meant using the close column is wrong. I implemented a similar solution to the answer provided, where I used macd

You can do it the foolowing way. First ensuring that the close column is correctly referenced and modify the compute_ema function so that it takes the df, column name, and period n as arguments.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'close': [22, 23, 23.5, 24, 25, 24.5, 24, 23.5, 23, 22.5, 22, 21.5, 21, 20.5, 20, 19.5, 19, 18.5, 18, 17.5, 17, 16.5, 16, 15.5, 15, 14.5, 14, 13.5, 13, 12.5, 12, 11.5, 11, 10.5, 10, 9.5, 9, 8.5, 8, 7.5, 7, 6.5, 6, 5.5, 5, 4.5, 4, 3.5, 3, 2.5, 2, 1.5, 1, 0.5]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def compute_ema(df, column, n):
    df['sma'] = df[column].rolling(n).mean()
    multiplier = 2 / (n + 1)
    df.dropna(inplace=True)
    df['ema'] = np.nan
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if i == 0:
            df.loc[df.index[i], 'ema'] = df.loc[df.index[i], 'sma']
        else:
            df.loc[df.index[i], 'ema'] = (df.loc[df.index[i], column] - df.loc[df.index[i - 1], 'ema']) * multiplier + df.loc[df.index[i - 1], 'ema']
    return df['ema']

df['fast'] = compute_ema(df.copy(), 'close', 12)
df['slow'] = compute_ema(df.copy(), 'close', 26)

df['macd'] = df['fast'] - df['slow']

df['signal'] = compute_ema(df.copy(), 'macd', 9)

print(df)

and get
    close       fast       slow      macd    signal
0    22.0        NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN
1    23.0        NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN
2    23.5        NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN
3    24.0        NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN
4    25.0        NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN
5    24.5        NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN
6    24.0        NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN
7    23.5        NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN
8    23.0        NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN
9    22.5        NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN
10   22.0        NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN
11   21.5  23.208333        NaN       NaN       NaN
12   21.0  22.868590        NaN       NaN       NaN
13   20.5  22.504191        NaN       NaN       NaN
14   20.0  22.118931        NaN       NaN       NaN
15   19.5  21.716019        NaN       NaN       NaN
16   19.0  21.298170        NaN       NaN       NaN
17   18.5  20.867682        NaN       NaN       NaN
18   18.0  20.426500        NaN       NaN       NaN
19   17.5  19.976269        NaN       NaN       NaN
20   17.0  19.518382        NaN       NaN       NaN
21   16.5  19.054015        NaN       NaN       NaN
22   16.0  18.584167        NaN       NaN       NaN
23   15.5  18.109680        NaN       NaN       NaN
...
50    2.0   4.748457   8.179799 -3.431342 -3.401996
51    1.5   4.248695   7.684999 -3.436304 -3.408858
52    1.0   3.748896   7.189814 -3.440918 -3.415270
53    0.5   3.249065   6.694272 -3.445207 -3.421257


I managed to fix the code it provides the values accurately.
def compute_ema(df,n,column_name):
    df['sma'] = df['close'].rolling(n).mean()
    multiplier = 2 / (n + 1)
    df.dropna(inplace=True)
    for i in range(1,len(df)):
        if i == 1:
            df.loc[df.index[i],column_name] = df.loc[df.index[i - 1],'sma']
        else:
            df.loc[df.index[i],column_name] = (df.loc[df.index[i],'close'] - df.loc[df.index[i - 1],column_name]) * multiplier + df.loc[df.index[i - 1],column_name]
    return df

def compute_signal(df,n):
    df['signal_sma'] = df['macd'].rolling(n).mean()
    multiplier = 2 / (n + 1)
    df.dropna(inplace=True)
    for i in range(1,len(df)):
        if i == 1:
            df.loc[df.index[i],'signal_ma'] = df.loc[df.index[i - 1],'signal_sma']
        else:
            df.loc[df.index[i],'signal_ma'] = (df.loc[df.index[i],'macd'] - df.loc[df.index[i - 1],'signal_ma']) * multiplier + df.loc[df.index[i - 1],'signal_ma']
    return df


date open   high    low close   volume  sma fast    slow    macd
                                    
2024-05-31 12:15:00+05:30   1425.60 1430.00 1425.25 1429.60 240778  1417.361538 1423.510969 NaN NaN
2024-05-31 12:20:00+05:30   1429.95 1431.75 1428.40 1430.00 235171  1418.375000 1424.509282 1417.361538 7.147743
2024-05-31 12:25:00+05:30   1430.50 1431.35 1428.65 1430.35 240939  1419.292308 1425.407854 1418.323647 7.084207
2024-05-31 12:30:00+05:30   1430.00 1433.75 1429.70 1433.00 263825  1420.394231 1426.575876 1419.410784 7.165092
2024-05-31 12:35:00+05:30   1433.15 1433.50 1431.50 1432.40 241099  1421.401923 1427.471895 1420.372948 7.098947

